# NetSuite Adjust Request for Realtime Shipping Rate Calculator

Tags: xml, request, netsuite, rate

I have items that are being stored in a system outside of NetSuite and when a Sales Order is created in NetSuite there are fields to enter a part number and its condition.  Then a button is clicked to use this information and hit an API to bring the item data into the item line.  On the item lines, the same non-inventory item is used on all lines.  NetSuite is setup to use real-time shipping rates from UPS with the standard NetSuite UPS integration.  I am bringing in the item weight data in with the rest of the item data and set the line item field 'weightinlbs' so that the rate request has the correct weight total.  I am able to see the request data that NetSuite is generating  and the weight value is changing, but for some reason the rate returned is always the same.  The weight doesn't seem to have any effect on the rate returned. Any help on being able to figure out why the weight isn't effecting the rate returned would be great. Thanks.

Here is a sample of the XML request generated by NetSuite when the calculator icon is clicked by the shipping cost field.

```
<RatesRequest>
<RequestSrc>SALESORDER</RequestSrc>
<RatesCarrier>upsRealTimeRate</RatesCarrier>
<EntityId>2589764</EntityId>
<IsItemLineRates>false</IsItemLineRates>
<DestCity>Sparks</DestCity>
<DestState>NV</DestState>
<DestZip>89431</DestZip>
<DestCountry>US</DestCountry>
<ShipMethod>4</ShipMethod>
<SalesOrderId/>
<IsResidential>F</IsResidential>
<IsThirdPartyAcct>F</IsThirdPartyAcct>
<ThirdPartyCarrier>ALL</ThirdPartyCarrier>
<IsPackagesReload>false</IsPackagesReload>
<IsDefaultRequest/>
<Currency>1</Currency>
<TransactionFxRate>1</TransactionFxRate>
<Subsidiary/>
<TestId/>
<NexusId/>
<OverrideShippingCost/>
<IsDynamicScriptingRequest>false</IsDynamicScriptingRequest>
<Packages></Packages>
<Items>
<Item>
<ItemQuantity>6</ItemQuantity>
<ItemAmount>93.06</ItemAmount>
<ItemWeight>1000</ItemWeight>
<ItemKey>107237</ItemKey>
<ItemLocation>1</ItemLocation>
<ItemUnits>1</ItemUnits>
<ItemType>NonInvtPart</ItemType>
<ItemExcludeFromRateRequest/>
<ItemShipAddrKey/>
<ItemShipAddr1/>
<ItemShipAddr2/>
<ItemShipCity/>
<ItemShipState/>
<ItemShipZip/>
<ItemShipCountry/>
<ItemShipIsResidential/>
<ItemShipMethKey/>
<ItemName/>
<ItemDescription>Item Description Here</ItemDescription>
<ItemCountryOfManufacture/>
<ItemProducer/>
<ItemExportType/>
<ItemManufacturerName/>
<ItemMultManufactureAddr/>
<ItemManufacturerAddr1/>
<ItemManufacturerCity/>
<ItemManufacturerState/>
<ItemManufacturerZip/>
<ItemManufacturerTaxId/>
<ItemManufacturerTariff/>
<ItemPreferenceCriterion/>
<ItemScheduleBNumber/>
<ItemScheduleBQuantity/>
<ItemScheduleBCode/>
<ItemUnitsDisplay/>
<ItemUnitPrice>15.51</ItemUnitPrice>
<ItemLine/>
<ItemTotalQuantity/>
<ItemQuantityRemaining/>
<ItemTotalAmount/>
</Item>
</Items>
</RatesRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

`weightinlbs` is not a standard schema field so if you are seeing it in the xml of the SO it's likely that is a read-only field. I've seen a number of cases where pieces of information written from the client to the back end are ignored and since you are sending an item Id I expect NS is just using that to lookup the configured weight.

The UPS rating API is pretty simple to use. You'd probably find it easier to integrate that and do the lookup than to try to get Netsuite to accept per-line weights.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking that NS was possibly doing a lookup on the item record as well, so I tried changing the item weight on the item record as a test and that still had no effect on the rate returned.  Yes the `weightinlbs` field isn't a standard schema field, but the value can be set via client script on the sales order.  I don't know if it would save the value, but I'm not really worried about that.  This is basically to just set the weight for the item  lines to be used for the rate.  The request and response that NS gets does include the adjusted weight value on both.

Comment: Pretty sweet if you can get this working. What happens if you vary the weights widely? Are you at some min or max of the method selected?

Comment: The rate never changes no matter how much I vary the weights right now.  I have made it so the total shipment weight vary from as little as 1 lb all the way up to 5000 lbs.  The rate returned is always $8.54.